# Azure Mobile App Offline Sync - URL length limitations, batched pulls, queryId length

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Schematically, I spend my time doing things looking like the following.

```
public async Task<ItemA> GetItemsA(object someParams)
{
    var res = new List<ItemA>();
    var listOfItemAIds = await GetIdsFromServerAsync(someParams);
    var tableAQuery = _tableA.Where(x => listOfItemAIds.Contains(x.Id));
    await _tableA.PullAsync(null, tableAQuery);
    var itemsA= await tableAQuery.ToListAsync();
    var listOfItemBIds = itemsA.Select(x => x.bId).ToList();
    await _tableB.PullAsync(null, _tableB.Where(x => listOfItemBIds .Contains(x.Id));
    foreach(var itemA in itemsA)
    {
        itemA.ItemB = await _tableB.LookupAsync(itemA.itemBId);
    }
    return res;
}
```

There are several problems with that:

- `listOfTableAIds.Contains(x.Id)` leads to errors due to URL length limitations
- As a cannot represent the content of `listOfItemAIds` or `listOfItemBIds` with a `queryId` of less than 50 chars, I end up pulling data that I might already have
- It's a shame that all my pulls are not batched into a single server call
- I could directly get all I need from a single server query but then I wouldn't benefit from the Azure Mobile Sync framework

Any suggestions on how to improve that sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you refine things so that you query is simpler.  You may overall pull more data, but then that data will be available within tableB.  For instance, you may want to say "where itemBId is not null".

Comment: Thanks a lor for having a look @adrian. However I cannot make it "simpler" hence my post. I'll end up redirecting the pullasync http get into custom http posts...